# Why don't template literal types work for names of object attributes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this simple JavaScript function

```
function retObj(suff, n) {
  const r = {[`fixed${suff}`]: n * 2};
  return r;
}

retObj('A', 3) // { fixedA: 6 }
```

Now if I want to add types to it, I tried like this:

```
type FixedWithSuffix<T extends string> = `fixed${T}`;

type ObjWithFixedField<T extends string> = {[k in FixedWithSuffix<T>]: number};

function retObj<T extends string>(suff: T, n: number): ObjWithFixedField<T> {
  return {[`fixed${suff}`]: n * 2};
}
```

Compiler reports error (although without strict mode it compiles and works):

`` Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [k in `fixed${T}`]: number; }'.(2322) ``

But the same thing works in a bit simpler situation, where function returns string:

```
type FixedWithSuffix<T extends string> = `fixed${T}`;

function retStr<T extends string>(suff: T): `fixed${T}` {
  return `fixed${suff}`;
}
```

Here is the code on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgDwgEwOp2ACwMoFcBm%20iAPACpQQLAQB2yAzlPcAE5w0DmAfFALxQADIkmQASAN6kAvgIDcAWABQS-LhoBjYHAD2NKCwjBsrMhSq0GTVu24AKegXwAuKKQCULoYhQTpAqOJKUFDqusz6LvAi6Fh4hCSkPPxeIhIOhDIKisEGwLgseixZUkpKoJBQAPIARgBWMZhRKPAQADbIppTUdIzMbJxJAQDaANZQ7LDeaBg4jglcALouNLgAttUQLFJZKmqaOoWGNbWd5j1W-Xbpzq4ANFA0y2sbLB5VdQ1NyC3tZDyB2RCYWAEWGYwmKR8khkSwez02Uj4w0hYnE1xhyygACooAAmbZBfSGfKFYqlRShGjhFgARiRuWMLFsAHIQBAQMy3FlKfRtK0IAA6VraDi2Wlc8k8kEsXH0o51Flsjn3XESilhPmC4WimUC4QoJVqoA).

Why is that?
Is it possible to add proper types to that function?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to probably move it into an overload:

```
type FixedWithSuffix<T extends string> = `fixed${T}`;

type ObjWithFixedField<T extends string> = { [k in FixedWithSuffix<T>]: number };

function retObj<T extends string>(suff: T, n: number): ObjWithFixedField<T>;
function retObj(suff: string, n: number) {
    const r = { [`fixed${suff}`]: n * 2 };

    return r;
}
```

Then you won't have to deal with the annoying types in the body.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOA37m)

Comment: I've edited the question to remove types in the body. I don't need your overload to get rid of types in function body, as they can be inferred. But, even if I just return value in function body, I still get error.  Your solution works, but I wounder why I can't write it directly instead of using overload?

Comment: Is the overload standard approach to such things?

Comment: @Marko Overloads aren't strictly checked by the compiler. They just need to be assignable to the definition's signature (here it is `(suff: string, n: number) => { [key: string]: number }`, which is okay since it is more "general" than `<T extends string>(suff: T, n: number) => ObjWithFixedField<T>`).